# SyntaxError: Unexpected token: operator (>)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, uglifyjs

I am using [react-bootstrap-typeahead](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap-typeahead) library in my React package.

I have added these import statements as per the documents:

```
import { Typeahead } from "react-bootstrap-typeahead";
import "react-bootstrap-typeahead/css/Typeahead.css";
```

and rendering:

```
<Typeahead
  id="basic-typeahead-example"
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  options={this.state.options}
  placeholder="Choose..."
/>
```

When try to build, I am getting:

```
static/js/main.4b322a5a.js from UglifyJs
SyntaxError: Unexpected token: operator (>) [./~/react-bootstrap-typeahead/~/escape-string-regexp/index.js:3,0]
```

Can some tell where is the actual problem as the code is running perfectly when I do npm run. Is there any problem with `react-bootstrap-typeahead` library?

Comment: This is likely a problem in your build pipeline. How are you using uglify? If you disable uglify does the problem persist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed the lower version for this library and it worked